# Unable to move turtlebot or create map when using custom world in Gazebo

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rtabmap-odometry, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to using ROS (and Ubuntu) and am reaching out as I've hit a snag.
I am trying to use the rtabmap_ros tutorial for [mapping and navigation using turtlebot](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/MappingAndNavigationOnTurtlebot) (the simulation portion) and am able to successfully create a map when using:

```
$roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch

$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch simulation:=true

$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_turtlebot_rviz.launch
```

However, when trying the same with a custom world that I've created, the world launches in Gazebo but

```
roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch simulation:=true g
```

throws the following error:

```
Could not get transform from odom to base_footprint after 0.200000 seconds (for stamp=1466.802000)! Error="Could not find a connection between 'odom' and 'base_footprint' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.. canTransform returned after 0.2 timeout was 0.2.
```

I used

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

and see that `odom` is not connected to `base_footprint`. I am not sure how to rectify this.

I am essentially trying to simulate a turtlebot and make it autonomously (without having to use any manual intervention) move around an unknown location  and create a map (SLAM) using Gazebo. If there are existing packages or codes that could help me with this please point me in the right direction. I use ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Best regards,
Malar.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327410/unable-to-move-turtlebot-or-create-map-when-using-custom-world-in-gazebo./) by [MalarJN](https://answers.ros.org/users/43729/malarjn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2019-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) on 2019-07-01**:
You forgot to include your error message, can you add it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

So, I tried this with a different custom world and it worked. The issue seems to occur when you add a standing person when creating the world in Gazebo. Also, as @matlabbe suggested [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/287706/simultaneous-autonomous-navigation-and-mapping/), I used [frontier_exploration](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration) to make the process autonomous. Giving the setup more time to execute builds a map of the Gazebo world. Thank you @matlabbe for all your help.
Best regards,
Malar.

---

Originally posted by [MalarJN](https://answers.ros.org/users/43729/malarjn/) with karma: 25 on 2019-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0